Xlsxwriter: Excel files saved on Sharepoint corrupted with embed_image function
I have the following section of my Python script that works perfectly fine locally but as soon as I work on remote files on a SharePoint site the Excel file becomes corrupted after running the script (see attached image). All other formatting tasks using xlsxwriter work perfectly fine on remote files on SH. I have included below the section of the script that causes the issue. I think it could come from the BytesIO used for the file and then the images, but I am not sure. And I have tried to re-initialize the BytesIO and/or close it in the loop and it does not work then (i.e. no embedded images) but the file is not corrupted anymore.
Do you have any idea what could cause this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help with this.


# Function to upload files to SharePoint
 def upload_file_to_sharepoint(access_token, site_id, library_id, folder_path, file_name, file_data):
     formatted_path = f"/{folder_path}/{file_name}".replace(" ", "%20")
     endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{library_id}/root:{formatted_path}:/content'
     headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
     response = requests.put(endpoint, headers=headers, data=file_data)
     if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
         print("File uploaded successfully.")
     else:
         print(f"Failed to upload file: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
      
# Create a new Excel file with xlsxwriter
    output_stream = BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_stream, {'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write data to Excel, consider URL formatting and image embedding
for row_num, row in enumerate(filtered_df.itertuples(index=False), start=1):
    # Set row height to 300 if the row has any data
     if any(pd.notna(value) for value in row):
         worksheet.set_row(row_num, 300)

    for col_num, value in enumerate(row):
        column_name = filtered_df.columns[col_num]
        # Determine the format based on whether the column is a designated URL column
        format_to_use = url_format if column_name in url_columns and pd.notna(value) else cell_format

# Handle specific behavior for image URLs in 'Post Overview'
        if column_name == 'Post Overview' and pd.notna(value):
            imgUrl = getattr(row, 'imgUrl', None)
            try:
                image_data = requests.get(imgUrl).content
                image_stream = BytesIO(image_data) 
                #image_stream.seek(0)  # Reset stream position. Test failed               
                worksheet.embed_image(row_num, col_num, 'image.png', {'image_data': image_stream})
                #image_stream.close() # Test failed
            except Exception as e:
                 print(f"Failed to load image from {imgUrl}: {e}")
                 worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, 'Failed to load image', format_to_use)
         else:
            worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, value if pd.notna(value) else '', format_to_use)        

workbook.close()
output_stream.seek(0)
processed_file_name = 'Processed_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.xlsx'
upload_file_to_sharepoint(access_token, config['site_id'], config['library_id'], config['folder_path'], processed_file_name, output_stream.read())
print("Excel file with images saved successfully.")

